# Llamar un css exclusivamente para un DIV

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, mediaqueries

estoy haciendo pruebas con pagina web. Tengo ya un sitio hecho, fue con bootstrap 5.2.
Creé otro sitio con un formulario, datetimepicker, etc basado en bootstrap v3.
Ahora me pregunto, quisiera que este formulario basado en v3, meterlo al otro sitio con boostrap v5 haciendo que exclusivamente el DIV donde se encuentre el formulario trabaje nomas con la version de bootstrap 3. Es decir llamar el CSS que yo elija solo para ese div.
Alguna idea para que un div trabaje con un CSS exclusivo?
Suena raro. pero habra alguna forma?
Intenté con con mediaquerie

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (max-width: 1200px)' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .formcontacto {
/*llamado del CSS*/
  }
}

<div class ="formcontacto">
  </div>
```

Comment: Lo más fácil es usar un iframe, lo otro que podría resultar es usar shadow DOM

Comment: Me podrias orientar mas o menos como seria ?

Comment: ah creo que ya pude hacerlo asi con un iframe Yussef